# Running two tasks simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Hi I have a winform application which consists of 25 text boxes which represent values received in real time while they have labels beneath them which shows min max and average of these values [flow in shown with red arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/115n2.jpg)

right now when application starts it populates data in each textbox and its label with a delay of 1 sec. So it takes 7 to 8 secs for it to completely populate the data.

what I want is to divide the task of filling text boxes and label into two portions.

I tried multithreading with it but it does not work for me

My code so far

```
        Thread mmathread;
        while (start)
        {
            try
            {
                RPM_TEXT.Text = ReadRPM().ToString() + " rpm";
                mmathread = new Thread(() => mma(rpm_list, ReadRPM(), RPM_mma));
                mmathread.Start();
                
            }
            catch { }

            try { EL_TEXT.Text = ReadEngineLoad().ToString() + " %";
                mmathread = new Thread(() => mma(el_list, ReadEngineLoad(), EL_mma));
                mmathread.Start();
                
            }
            catch { }
            try { ECT_TEXT.Text = ReadCoolantTemp().ToString() + " °C";
                mmathread = new Thread(() => mma(ect_list, ReadCoolantTemp(), ECT_mma));
                mmathread.Start();
                }
            catch { }
            }
```

The function definition is

```
private void mma(List<int> parameter_list, int parameter, Label label)
            {
            if (parameter_list.Count == 9) { parameter_list.Add(parameter); 
            parameter_list.RemoveAt(0); }
            else { parameter_list.Add(parameter); }
            minpara = parameter_list.Min();
            maxpara = parameter_list.Max();
            avrgpara = parameter_list.Sum() / parameter_list.Count;

            label.Text = $"Min = {minpara}, Avg = {avrgpara}, Max = {maxpara}";
            }
```

If i call the function directly it updates the label but if i add thread to it the label does not populate

Comment: Empty `try..catches` are usually bad.  You shouldn't touch GUI controls with a non-GUI thread.  Those calls need to be invoked.

Comment: You can't directly access UI elements (any UI elements, in any way) from the non-UI thread.  If you try, it may fail, your app may hang or you may get an exception (it depends).  In Windows Forms, all controls (including the Form (which inherits from `Control`) have a property `InvokeRequired` which is true if you are on a non-UI thread, and a method (`Invoke`) that will marshal your call to the UI thread.  Take a look at @BojanB's and my answers for the traditional way (in WinForms) to use this.

Comment: @adnan: You asked a question.  You got three answers.  Do you have any questions bout any of them? Do any of them help?  Does one of them perfectly answer your question?  We put some effort into helping you.  Some feedback, any feedback, would be useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Elaborating on @BojanB's answer, you can use the traditional WinForms `InvokeRequired`/`Invoke` pattern.  The `InvokeRequired` property returns true if it's evaluated on the non-UI thread.  If an `Invoke` call is required, then you just `Invoke` the same call (marshaling the call onto the UI thread) and it will complete.  If you do it this way, then the same function can be called from either the UI thread or any other thread.

First I created these three helper functions:

```
private void SetTextBoxFromThread(TextBox textBox, string contents)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<TextBox, string>(SetTextBoxFromThread), new object[] { textBox, contents });
        return;
    }

    textBox.Text = contents;
}

private string ReadTextBoxFromThread(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        return (string)Invoke(new Func<TextBox, string>(ReadTextBoxFromThread), new[] { textBox });
    }

    return textBox.Text;
}
private void SetLabelFromThread(Label label, string contents)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<Label, string>(SetLabelFromThread), new object[] { label, contents });
        return;
    }

    label.Text = contents;
}
```

With those in hand, I tested them by using this stupid little thread function (that matches an `async` version of the `ThreadStart` delegate):

```
private int isPaused = 0;       //used like a bool, int for clear atomicity

private async void ThreadFunc()
{
    while (isPaused == 0)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var str1 = now.ToString("T");
        var str2 = now.ToString("t");
        var str3 = now.ToString("s");

        SetTextBoxFromThread(textBox1, str1);
        SetTextBoxFromThread(textBox2, str2);
        SetTextBoxFromThread(textBox3, str3);

        await Task.Delay(1500);

        SetLabelFromThread(label1, ReadTextBoxFromThread(textBox1));
        SetLabelFromThread(label2, ReadTextBoxFromThread(textBox2));
        SetLabelFromThread(label3, ReadTextBoxFromThread(textBox3));
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I tested this in a long-lived thread (because it was easy to do).  Running these methods (`SetTextBoxFromThread` and friends) from inside a short-lived workload running on a thread-pool thread would work the same way.  They simple provide a way to set (or read) the text in a textbox or label from any thread.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Threads you need to use Invoke on the label. Like this

```
 label.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate () {label.Text = $"Min = {minpara}, Avg = {avrgpara}, Max = {maxpara}"};
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=net-5.0

Comment: I tried it but this make updating of label more slow then when I was doing it manually

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1)s instead of [`Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread)s¹. The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method offloads the supplied action to the `ThreadPool`, and the result of the action is later available through the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) property of the `Task<T>`. You can [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) the `Task<T>`s, so that the UI will remain responsive while the actions are running in the background. You can also start multiple tasks at once, so that the actions are invoked in parallel. In this case you can `await` all parallel tasks with the `Task.WhenAll` method. Example:

```
while (start)
{
    Task delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Task<string> task1 = Task.Run(() => ReadRPM());
    Task<string> task2 = Task.Run(() => ReadEngineLoad());
    Task<string> task3 = Task.Run(() => ReadCoolantTemp());
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
    RPM_TEXT.Text = task1.Result;
    EL_TEXT.Text = task2.Result;
    ECT_TEXT.Text = task3.Result;
    await delayTask;
}
```

In this example I've added a `Task.Delay` task, to impose a maximum frequency of one loop per second.

This code must be placed inside a method (or event handler) having the [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) modifier, to enable the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator.

¹ <sub>I am referring to the `Thread` class, not to the [thread as a concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)).</sub>

Comment: It's worth nothing that `Task.Run` will run the specified work on a background thread.  You're not using _" `Task<T>`s instead of threads"_, you are using them to represent threads.  In this case, you are scheduling work on three threads, waiting until the work on all three threads completes (`WhenAll`) and then updating the UI.  This will work, and may be what the OP wants.  Typically, though, when you are working with real-time systems, you work with long-lived threads that marshal data to the UI thread periodically.

Comment: @Flydog57 what's the advantage of using long-lived threads over using `ThreadPool` threads, for reading information about the system?

Comment: Well, it depends. Many of the control systems I've worked on have a strict separation of concerns between the control domain (running in its own threads, with it's own strict timing requirements) and the UI domain (where responsiveness is key, and being off by a 250-500 ms isn't a problem).  It really depends on how the OP wants his system to run.  There's nothing wrong with your solution, assuming it meets the OP's needs.  I was just pointing out that you were using thread-pool threads, and you were waiting till they all finished before updating the UI.

Comment: @Flydog57 one disadvantage of using the `ThreadPool` I can think of, is that in case the program schedules periodically more work to the `ThreadPool`, the pool may become saturated, and the UI may not be updated with fresh values for a few seconds (without becoming non-responsive). This will be a temporary issue though, because the `ThreadPool` will soon inject more threads to the pool (about one new thread every second), and the available threads will be enough.